# Display all the title of a Post type, and highlight the current page when redirect

Tags: php, wordpress

So this is my code and its doing its job for calling the titles from post type.  So for this sample its calling the titles like this

Title I 
Title II 
Title II

This list are also links,if I click "Title II" it redirects in the right single page but my problem is it doesn't highlight the current single page. In other words I want to make it look  like this:

Title I 
**Title II** 
Title II

but my code results is like this:
Title I 
Title II 
Title II

Below is my code in my page and this is also my code in my single page.

```
<?php $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'services',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
             $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile?>
            <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use ID to compare. Please remember to get current ID before the loop

```
<?php 
// Remember to get ID before the loop to have current ID
$current_post_ID = get_the_ID();
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'services',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a <?php echo $current_post_ID === get_the_ID() ? 'class="active"' : '' ?> href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endwhile?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do a test to see if the link for each post matches the current page URL.

```php
<?php
global $wp;
$current_url = home_url( $wp->request ) . '/';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'services',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li <?php if ( $current_url == get_the_permalink() ) { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```